# I have deployed a simple ASP.NET MVC application in nginx+fastcgi, but only the root folder is loading

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nginx, mono

Why is there an error on the ASP.NET MVC app when nginx+fastcgi navigates to folder? When the same path is loaded on xsp4 it has no error

This works on nginx: http://sampledomain.com

This didn't work on nginx: http://sampledomain.com/Home/Index

However, when the code is running in xsp4 (running the same code on a directory nginx+fastcgi is running in), both of the above works, i.e., this works on xsp4:

http://sampledomain.com:8080

http://sampledomain.com:8080/Home/Index

What could the possible missing configuration I need to configure on nginx?

Comment: What is the error you got? What is the configuration of your site? Do you try to navigate to directory or to the handler? Please provide more information. Does `http://sampledomain.com/Home/Index/` (backslash at the end) work in your configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just removed the following on /etc/nginx/sites-available/default:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
```

And it works now